# VACUUM/OPTIMIZE Effect on Autoloader Checkpoints

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using Databricks Autoloader to incrementally stream from a Delta Lake table into a SQL database.  If an OPTIMIZE or VACUUM statement is ran against the Delta table, new files are added/subtracted.

My question is, will the autoloader checkpoint discount these optimized files on the next stream?  Or will my entire Delta table be streamed into SQL because autoloader doesn't recognize it's already processed the data?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you specify the format of the readStream correctly, the autoloader checkpoint will disregard all aggregated files created by OPTIMIZE command. In this case, the code should be started as follows.  `df.readStream.format('delta')`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your stream checkpoint will consider the last position in the `_delta_log` given you are working with a delta table. After Vacuuming / Optimizing a new version will be created in the delta log with the changes.

Additionally, since you are using autoloader (and consequently streaming) check if the following options are not worth enabling:

```
delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite

delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact
```